# how do I get month from date in mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phrase

I want to be able to fetch results from mysql with a statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE amount > 1000
```

But I want to fetch the result constrained to a certain a month and year (based on input from user)...  I was trying like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE amount > 1000 
   AND dateStart = MONTH('$m')
```

...`$m` being a month but it gave error.

In that table, it actually have two dates:  `startDate` and `endDate` but I am focusing on `startDate`. The input values would be month and year. How do I phrase the SQL statement that gets the results based on that month of that year?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it your intentions are clear to a human. Computers are stupid.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You were close - got the comparison backwards (assuming `startDate` is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE amount > 1000 
   AND MONTH(dateStart) = {$m}
```

### Caveats:

---

- Mind that you are using [mysql_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) or you risk [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).
- Function calls on columns means that an index, if one exists, can not be used

### Alternatives:

---

Because using functions on columns can't use indexes, a better approach would be to use `BETWEEN` and the `STR_TO_DATE` functions:

```
WHERE startdate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE([start_date], [format]) 
                    AND STR_TO_DATE([end_date], [format])
```

See the documentation for formatting syntax.

### Reference:

---

- [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
- [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)
- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 8):

Use the `month()` function.

```
select month(now());
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the answer as-is provides next to no help give the question.

Answer (score 3):

E.g.

```
$date = sprintf("'%04d-%02d-01'", $year, $month);
$query = "
  SELECT
    x,y,dateStart
  FROM
    tablename
  WHERE
    AND amount > 1000
    AND dateStart >= $date
    AND dateStart < $date+Interval 1 month
";
mysql_query($query, ...
```

This will create a query like e.g.

```
WHERE
  AND amount > 1000
  AND dateStart >= '2010-01-01'
  AND dateStart < '2010-01-01'+Interval 1 month
```

`+ Interval 1 month` is an alternative to  [date_add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

`SELECT Date('2010-01-01'+Interval 1 month)`-> `2010-02-01`
`SELECT Date('2010-12-01'+Interval 1 month)`-> `2011-01-01`
This way you always get the first day of the following month. The records you want must have a dateStart before that date but after/equal to the first day of the month (and year) you've passed to sprintf().
`'2010-01-01'+Interval 1 month` doesn't change between rows. MySQL will calculate the term only once and can utilize indices for the search.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE amount > 1000 AND MONTH(dateStart) = MONTH('$m') AND YEAR(dateStart) = YEAR('$m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
      FROM table 
     WHERE amount > 1000 
       AND MONTH(datestart)
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datestart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if(date field is text then convert this string to date):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y'))='11'

//This will give month number MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y'))
//If its return 11 then its November
// Change date format with your date string format  %d/%m/%Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in:   MySQL 5.7, MySQL 5.6, MySQL 5.5, MySQL 5.1, MySQL 5.0, MySQL 4.1, MySQL 4.0, MySQL 3.23

- Day:

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM "2017-06-15");
  ```
- Month:

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15");
  ```
- Year:

  ```
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "2017-06-15");
  ```