# Add date to 1st record per month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a guestbook script and wish to add month and year to the first post of each month like Instagram profiles [demo](http://instagram.com/priruflles)

so my question is how can I grab month and year from db timestamp and add to first record per month?

db structure:

```
post
--id
--msg
--dt (timestamp)
```

I know (and am sorry) this is a bit of a "can you do the work for me" post but I haven't got a clue where I would start.

tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(dt), YEAR(dt) AS month FROM post GROUP BY MONTH(dt)
```

...

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM post ORDER BY dt DESC
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you talk about the db's or php's timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670910/how-to-get-month-using-date-in-mysql

Comment: db timestamp, op ammended, i've tried a couple of things but like I said I haven't been successful

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the needed images (all or maybe only a part of them, if there are a lot) ordered by the `dt` field in decreasing order.
2. Iterate through the selection result and print out the pictures.
3. When the n+1. picture's date has a different month, than the previous one (the n. picture), then show the date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code-snippet might help you.

It prints out the Month and Year only on a new month.

To format a timestamp you can use the `date("format", timestamp)` function.

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) for more information.

```
 <?php
        $currentMonth = "";
        //Your timestamps, here saved in an array and ordered!!
        $array_with_timestamps...
        //Execute for each value in the array
        foreach($array_with_timestamps as $timstamp) {
            //If the month of this timestamp is unequal to the value in $currentMonth
            //then echo "Monthname Year" of this timestamp
            if ($currentMonth != date('F', $timestamp)) { 
                echo date('F', $timestamp)." ".date('Y', $timestamp);
                //Set this month now as the currentMonth
                $currentMonth = date('F', $timestamp);
            }
            //Print picture
        }
  ?>
```