# How to select only month from date field?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database record of payments. In `date` field I have all 3 option `dd-month-year` from a date-picker.

[image: datebase of payment]

Now I want to know total payment submit of a month or any specific date for date.

```
   if($_POST['date']!='' ){
      $query ="SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_sum FROM payment where date='".$_POST['date']."' ";
      $result=mysql_query($query,$con);
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
      $sum = $row['value_sum'];
   }
```

How can I count total `submit` of a month from this table?

For month I am using:

```
<p class="name">
<td>
  <label for="name1">By Month</label>
</td>
<td>
<select name="month">
  <option>Month</option>
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
</td>
</p>
```

Comment: what is the type of date column? is it a date type or varchar?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=select+only+month+from+date+in+mysql+database&oq=select+only+month+from+date+in+mysql+database&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.1818j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Would saying use PDO or MySQLi offend you? Because if not... Use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: This question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039839/how-do-i-get-month-from-date-in-mysql. Look up MONTHNAME() : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Comment: ya,data type is varchar

Comment: what changes i have to done and how to write its query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query ="SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_sum FROM payment where date LIKE '%".$_POST['date']."%' ";
```

With something like this you get all results where, for example, date has 'MAY' in it.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably best to extract the month from `date` using MySQL's `MONTH()` function. So, assuming that you can arrange for January to be passed as 1, February as 2, etc. use a query like

```
SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_SUM
FROM payment
WHERE MONTH(date)=required_month
AND YEAR(date)=required_year
```

Take a look at the MySQL [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) when you have a minute.

After checking that link, I see there's a `MONTHNAME` function which would work if you're getting passed January, February etc. In that case, the query is

```
SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_sum
FROM payment
WHERE MONTHNAME(date)=required_month
AND YEAR(date)=required_year
```

**Editted** to add `AND YEAR...` to both queries after comment from Barmar. Of course, if you *do* want the total for all January's, you can leave this out. Also, if you don't want to make your user specify the current year, or you want it to default, arrange that `required_year` is `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())` in your PHP code.

**Editted** again after the OPs comment below, and taking into account his comment above that `date` is `varchar`.

I assume that `$_POST['date']`contains a date in the month you want the totals from. Substitute the lines below for your line `$query = ...'

```
$query =  'SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_sum FROM payment';
$query .= 'WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(datetime, date))';
$query .= '=MONTH(CONVERT(datetime,' . $_POST['date'] . '))';
$query .= 'AND YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, date))';
$query .= '=YEAR(CONVERT(datetime, ' . $_POST['date'] . '))';
```

Comment: This will combine months in different years, which is probably not what is wanted.

Comment: This answer is quite logical after the edit: Selecting the specific month from a specific year makes sense after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(submit) AS value_sum FROM payment where date BETWEEN $_POST['date1'] AND     
$_POST['date2'];
```