# Coldfusion CFQUERY w/ Inner Join & Dateformat Not Working

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I am trying to wrap my head around dealing joins, mysql and coldfusion.  The following query works without the last condition.

```
        <cfquery name="GetWeekends">
        SELECT w.id, w.weekend_type, w.community_id, w.start_date, w.end_date,
          w.language,
          c.community_id, c.location, c.language, c.state, c.country
        FROM _weekends w
        INNER JOIN _communities c
        ON w.community_id=c.community_id
        WHERE w.weekend_type = 1 AND w.start_date > Now() AND           
        #DateFormat(w.start_date, "m")# = '#form.home_by_month#'
        ORDER BY w.start_date ASC
        </cfquery>
```

It is dying on

```
  #DateFormat(w.start_date, "m")#
```

telling me variable [W] doesn't exist.  Sorry, I am learning as I go here...

Comment: By 'dying on' does that mean it comes with an error?

Comment: Yes, " variable [W] doesn't exist"

Comment: Also, I highly suggest using cfquery param to sanitize your variable. I'm pretty sure you don't need octothorps inside the query tag but it's been over a year since I've work a cfquery.

Comment: Ahhh I don't think you can apply a non SQL function to a query like that

Comment: I need to get the month (i,e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, or 12)  out of w.start_date, which is stored in MySQL as a DATE - and compare it to what I am passing in #form.home_by_month#

Comment: I know it's a PHP question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039839/how-do-i-get-month-from-date-in-mysql but I think you're looking for the MYSQL function `MONTH()`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much.  Learning Learning Learning!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that `DateFormat()` is a ColdFusion function, and that cannot be applied with a MySQL "variable" (`w`). You need to use the `MONTH()` function for MySQL and pass the date into that.

Don't forget to sanitize your form inputs, you are highly susceptible to SQL injection. Use [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) like so:

```
MONTH(w.start_date) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#form.home_by_month#" />
```

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for comments...)

Since you mentioned being new to CF, a little background on how CF processes database queries may help in understanding why the error occurred and what types of things you can (and cannot) do within a cfquery.

Although CF can communicate with a database engine, the two are totally separate, and speak completely different languages. **The fact that you can mix CFML and SQL within a cfquery tag gives the misleading impression that CF functions can operate on database objects** (or vice versa). They can't. The CF server knows nothing about database objects (nor does the database engine understand CFML). Any CFML code within the query tag is processed *first* - on the CF server. The generated SQL is then sent to the database engine, and executed separately.

When the CF server encounters a database query, it parses the tag contents, looking for CFML variables or expressions which must be evaluated, ie:

```
SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE ColA = '#form.someField#' AND ColB = '#form.otherField#'
```

It then converts those variables and expressions into literal values, ie strings, numbers, etcetera. Finally, CF hands the *generated* SQL string off to the database engine for execution, ie:

```
SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE ColA = 'John Smith' AND ColB = 'ABC'
```

So the reason CF chokes on `#DateFormat(w.start_date, "m")#` is that it does not understand `w.start_date` refers to a database column.  It thinks it is the name of a CF variable: specifically a structure named "w", containing the key "start_date". Obviously no such variables exist. Hence the undefined error.

Comment: This is a very good explanation of how language variables and database variables coexist in a query. (Also, hi Leigh!)

Comment: Thanks Sterling. In *some* ways, it is analogous to mixing client (JS) and server side code (CF) within the same script. Just because you can mix them, does not mean the CF server can execute client side code, or vice versa ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The working solution was, thanks to Sterling Archer:

```
<cfquery name="GetWeekends">
    SELECT w.id
           , w.weekend_type
           , w.community_id
           , w.start_date
           , w.end_date
           , w.language
           , c.community_id
           , c.location
           , c.language
           , c.state
           , c.country
    FROM   _weekends w INNER JOIN _communities c ON w.community_id = c.community_id
    WHERE w.weekend_type = 1 
    AND   w.start_date > Now() 
    AND   MONTH(w.start_date) = '#form.home_by_month#'
    ORDER BY w.start_date ASC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: If this is your solution, you should take Sterling's advice of also using `cfqueryparam`. Always use `cfqueryparam` when sending parameters in a database query.

Comment: Also, filtering on a month and not the year can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: In addition, if you are searching for records for a specific month *and* year, consider using [this paradigm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666883/date-comparison-in-ms-sql-2005/13687006#13687006), which is more flexible - not to mention index friendly - than using `Month()`.

Comment: Dan, of course.  In the case of this query, I am actually looking for results from a specific month, regardless of year.

Comment: (Edit) @mck - Yes, if you are looking for a specific month (for any year in the future) then that is a legitimate use of month(). BTW, not sure if it is relevant in this case, but keep in mind `now()` includes both a date and time. So the comparison would exclude records having the same date, but an earlier time.